# Accessing elements inside .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Probably a simple question, but here goes.

I have a legend on my map that contains some checkboxes when I mouseover it. 
I want to turn some of the elements inside the legend into jquery buttons.  For example, $("#unions").button();  However, I can't seem to access the elements inside the legend.

How would I do this? I have all the jquery files in my code, so that's not the problem.

```
var legend = '<ul>'
                       + '<li>   <b>            Organization Type:                  </b><li>'
                       + '<li> <input type="checkbox" id="unions" /> Unions '
                       + '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="nonunions" /> Non-Unions </li>'
                       +'<li>    <b>            Sectors (Union and Non-Union):      </b> <li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id = "agriculture" /> Agriculture</li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id = "processing" /> Food Processing</li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id = "warehouse"/> Warehouse</li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id = "retail" /> Retail</li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id = "food" /> Food Service</li>'
                       + '<li>    <b>           Non-Union Organization Type:            </b> <li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id="advocacy" = "adv"/> Advocacy</li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id = "service"/> Service</li>'
                       + '<li class="item"><input type="checkbox" name="radio" id = "workcenter" /> Work Center</li>'
                       + '</ul>';

$(controlLegend).html(legend);
```

Comment: What you currently have works just fine in fiddle, given fixed typos. (missing `$` and `"`)

Comment: The `$("#unions")` selector definitely works: http://jsfiddle.net/TDQm2/

Comment: For whatever reason, Musa's suggestion works,     `$("#unions").button();` doesn't.  Must be something else in my code.

Comment: This is not a Google Maps API 3 question. (tag removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#unions").button();` wouldn't work if `controlLegend` wasn't part of the DOM. You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get to the element inside of `controlLegend`.

```
$(controlLegend).find("#unions").button();
```

Comment: @nnnnnn Since `$("#unions").button();` didn't work I assumed that `controlLegend` wasn't part of the DOM.

Comment: Ah, OK. +1 in advance on the assumption that you move that explanation into your actual answer.